# Xcode Thread Signal Error & local declaration error

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, multithreading

I'm getting this error when attempting to run an app on the simulator.

Any suggestions what it is? I'm also getting this error too which is boggling my mind I've supplied some code, let me know if you need more!

Thanks :)

**Thread Error**

```
{
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
}
```

**Second Error: Local declaration of 'MyHero' hides instance variable**

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];

    world = [SKNode node];
    [self addChild:Myhero];


    SKSpriteNode *ground = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor blueColor]      size:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 100)];
    ground.position = CGPointMake(0, -self.frame.size.height/2 + ground.frame.size.height/2);
    ground.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:ground.size];
    ground.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    [self addChild:ground];

    Hero *Myhero = [Hero Myhero];
    [world addChild:Myhero];
```

Answer (score 0):

The first error would need more details to troubleshoot, but the second error should be a quick fix - you have a naming conflict.  Change the last two lines of your initWithSize: method to the following

```
Hero *hero= [Hero Myhero];
[world addChild:hero];
```

That should straighten it out.

Comment: That didn't work, not it's telling me No visible @interface declares the selector hero. It's also saying Unused Variable hero :(

Comment: Sorry, I left out the method name addChild:  Try it now.

Comment: that worked, thanks :) getting another error now which is stupid!it's Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x14) it's on the following code          }

-(void)didSimulatePhysics
{
    [self centerOnNode:Myhero];
}
-(void)centerOnNode:(SKNode *)node
{
    CGPoint positionInScene = [self convertPoint:node.position fromNode:node.parent];    world.position = CGPointMake(world.position.x - positionInScene.x, world.position.y - positionInScene.y);
}

Comment: Looks like you are referencing something that has been freed up from a memory perspective.  If I had to guess, I'd say it may be node.parent?  The best way to tell would be to set a debug breakpoint at the top of the method and step through until you hit the exception.

Comment: so it looks like the error is on this bit of code according to the debug      
-(void)didSimulatePhysics
{
    [self centerOnNode:Myhero];
}
-(void)centerOnNode:(SKNode *)node
{
    CGPoint positionInScene = [self convertPoint:node.position fromNode:node.parent];    world.position = CGPointMake(world.position.x - positionInScene.x, world.position.y - positionInScene.y);
}